# Firebase Document ID based on certain chatroom

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to make a chat app, and by data structure is like this:

Database - Collection - Document - Collection - Document [image: Firebase setup]

[image]

The first collection is for the chatrooms and the first document is info about each chatroom. The second collection and document are where the messages are in. Here is the code I have written for the chatroom:

```
    function createRoom(chatName) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').add({
        chatName: chatName,
        roomCreator: getUserID(),
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error writing new message to Firebase Database', error);
      });
}

function saveMessage(messageText) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('chatroomvalue').collection('messages').add({
        message: messageText,
        user: getUserID(),
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error writing new message to Firebase Database', error);
      });
}
```

I was wondering how I can make it so that when a user opens a certain chatroom, type in a message and have that message saved as a document in the appropriate chatroom. Is there a way to pull the ID of the chatroom and also tell if a certain chatroom is open? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried listing all chatrooms by using ```get()``` function? You can access the id of each documents by getting ```doc.id```. You can refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: You would want to store the id of the document first in a local state/variable after entering to a specific chatroom. Then when sending a message you could use that id as your ```chatroomvalue```

Comment: Can you share the code where you fetch the chatroom data? If you are using `get()` you can use the method that @blankart mentioned above.

Comment: Is it possible if I do this.doc.id?

Comment: it depends, if you map the value that comes from the `get()` to a global variable called `doc` you might be able to do it, however, I would recommend you choose a different name for that variable. Check the documentation provided by blankart earlier for the usage of `get()`